# Dependencey Property with New Object in designer

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I am struggling to find information about how to add some extra functionality in Visual Studio for dependency properties.

Basically, I want to create a similar function as the Effect property on most controls. If I press the Effects' new button, a list of possible effect objects are shown.

This is what I am used to for DP

```
        public MyClass MyClass 
        {
            get { return (MyClass)GetValue(MyClassProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyClassProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyClassProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyClass", typeof(MyClass),
            typeof(MyView),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new MyClass(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, MyClassPropertyChangedCallback));

        private static void MyClassPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = d as MyView;
            control.MyClass = (MyClass)e.NewValue;
        }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Your question suggests that you want to incorporate a DependencyProperty called Effect, but your code sample doesn't include anything by that name. Can you rephrase the question at all?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the question, hopefully it is better now.

Comment: I think visual studio does that automatically when you are using an enum as type

Comment: @Dominik I am not sure what you mean. I only know of two specified types in a DP, one for the owner and one for the object. My object is a class object.

Comment: I meant the object. afaik, if you are using an enum as type, instead of object, visual studio will automatically suggest the possible values.

Comment: @Dominik ah ok. I am wonder regarding normal class object. But I guess my question is too vague, and nobody actually uses the Effects on most controls

Comment: I was just looking a bit deeper and found that the Brush class is annotated with a TypeConverter implementation (BrushConverter). Maybe this can get you started